# Orangescrum css and js links not working

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

I installed Orangescrum on my localhost and its working fine, But when I upload it to my live server I am getting Internal Server Error error. I checked the codes and I commented `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` from app/webroot/.htaccess, the Internal server error has gone but the css and js links is not working.

Comment: That line is important. If you comment that line out, every single request will be passed to your index.php-file (including requests to your existing js-, css-, image-files and what not). If you get an internal server error, you should check your web servers error log to find out what the actual error message is. Without that, it's pretty hard to debug.

Comment: Just a side note, irrespectively of your problem, but maybe you should look into the professional/paid version, the community version hasn't really had any proper updates in years, and the overall code quality is rather awful (sorry if I'm stepping on anyone's toes here). Just had a look at it for a minute and I'm already overwhelmed by the amount of SQL injection vulnerabilities...

Comment: Request exceeded the limit of 20 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'Limit Internal Recursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace. - this is the server log